# Convert char[] arrays to String

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array :

```
char[] chars={'X','X','m','a','t','t','X','X'};
```

I want to create String with value "matt", so starting from chars' index 2 to 5. Is there a built-in method to achieve this, or I must do looping?

Comment: @aioobe : my char[] is of ascii characters .. but here i've just shown one sample of it ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) String constructor, so

```
new String(chars,2,4);
```

Answer (score 5):

check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html there is a String constructor with a offset

i.e. `new String(chars,2,4);`

Answer (score 3):

```
String mattString = new String(chars, 2, 4);
```

Comment: A bit late, but still +1 for following §8.2 of java code conventions and having a space after each comma in argument list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
char[] chars = ...;
String out = new String(chars,2,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

String x = new String(chars).replaceAll("X","");

Answer (score 0):

Org.apache package

new String(ArrayUtils.subarray(char[], int start, int end));